# Kotlin - Is there a way to pass property values to another object with properties of the same name?

Tags: kotlin, data-class

Is there a way to pass property values to another object with properties of the same name to avoid having "repeated" code?

For example, avoid having where `CepReceiptsInfo` is different class than `value` but they share some properties name and type :

```
   val cepReceiptsInfo = CepRecepitsInfo()
    cepReceiptsInfo.operationTimestamp = value.operationTimestamp
    cepReceiptsInfo.sentDate = value.sentDate
    cepReceiptsInfo.sentTime = value.sentTime
    cepReceiptsInfo.concept = value.concept
    cepReceiptsInfo.referenceNumber = value.referenceNumber
    cepReceiptsInfo.amount = value.amount
    cepReceiptsInfo.trackingKey = value.trackingKey
    cepReceiptsInfo.bankTarget = value.bankTarget
    cepReceiptsInfo.bankSource = value.bankSource
    cepReceiptsInfo.sourceClienteName = value.sourceClienteName
    cepReceiptsInfo.beneficiaryName = value.beneficiaryName
    cepReceiptsInfo.accountNumberTarget = value.accountNumberTarget
    cepReceiptsInfo.term = value.term
    cepReceiptsInfo.authorizationNumber = value.authorizationNumber
    cepReceiptsInfo.linkCep = value.linkCep
    cepReceiptsInfo.status = value.status
    cepReceiptsInfo.bankSourceRefund = value.bankSourceRefund
    cepReceiptsInfo.causeRefund = value.causeRefund
    cepReceiptsInfo.accountTargetRefund = value.accountTargetRefund
    cepReceiptsInfo.currency = value.currency
    cepReceiptsInfo.accountNumberSource = value.accountNumberSource
    cepReceiptsInfo.accountTypeSource = value.accountTypeSource
    cepReceiptsInfo.accountTypeTarget = value.accountTypeTarget
    cepReceiptsInfo.indicatorRefund = value.indicatorRefund
    cepReceiptsInfo.amountIntRefund = value.amountIntRefund
    cepReceiptsInfo.operationRefundTimestamp = value.operationRefundTimestamp
    cepReceiptsInfo.dateMovement = value.dateMovement
    cepReceiptsInfo.timeMovement = value.timeMovement
    cepReceiptsInfo.dateRefund = value.dateRefund
    cepReceiptsInfo.timeRefund = value.timeRefund
```

to something like f.e.:

```
val cepReceiptsInfo = CepReceintsInfo()
cepReceiptsInfo.assignFrom(value)
```

both Classes are **data classes**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way without reflection.

```
fun Any.assignFrom(other: Any) {
    val thisProperties = this::class.memberProperties
        .filterIsInstance<KMutableProperty<*>>()
        .map { it.name to it }
        .toMap()
    for (property in other::class.memberProperties){
        thisProperties[property.name]?.setter?.call(this, property.getter.call(other))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Tenfour04 says, the language doesn't provide a direct way of doing this, so you're limited to using extra compile-time tools, or Reflection at runtime.

Since this is a fairly common problem, there's a Java library called [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) which does this for you; and as with just about all Java libraries, you can use it in Kotlin too.

(I've used it on occasion.  It can avoid lots of boilerplate.  Though I didn't find it as refactoring-safe as the front page claims…  It also ‘hides’ references to fields in a way that IDEs won't track.  So it's not a perfect solution.)